# Android Contacts Issues

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I have been doing a lot of searching around, looking for a sample project of something showing   me how can extract the contact from android phone, and move to a separate data storage and display it on my app. Can some one help me, please.....

Comment: from contact db what you  need only name?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650750/how-to-get-mobile-number-form-contact & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476957/where-to-store-a-contact-list-on-an-android-phone

Answer (score 0):

Method to get contacts

```
public List<String> lookupContactNames(){
    contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        final String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP
                + " = '1'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        final String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
        cursor = contentResolver.query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            contacts
                    .add(cursor
                            .getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        }
        return contacts;
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

}
```